# * ERROR: nrpe does not have a start function

Tags: nagios, gentoo, nrpe

I installed Nagios-NRPE on a Gentoo virtual machine.

When I tried to start nrpe using `/etc/init.d/nrpe start` I got the following error:

```
ERROR:  nrpe does not have a start function.
```

However I do not get this error on other Gentoo virtual machines on which I have installed Nagios-NRPE.

What might be causing this error?

Comment: Off topic here, but have a look at /etc/init.d/nrpe. There must be no start function in the init script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case it was a simple matter of installing `openrc` using `emerge`:

emerge -avq openrc

It seems that `openrc` provides a necessary service to interpret `start` for certain scripts including `/etc/init.d/nrpe`.

Comment: Thanks, Barnaby.

Much needed info! (irony precluded)